# Access NodePort service through different URL

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, dns, virtual-machine

I have a webapp deployed on Kubernetes running on a VM and I can access it on my PC through `http://node-ip1:31000`.

However, I want to add a second VM, also running that app, which will have its own IP and be accessed by `http://node-ip2:31000`. But it doesn't make much sense that we have to access an app through another IP if one fails, is there an easy way to map the NodePort to a URL like `http://my-app`? I know it can be done with a DNS server but I don't know how or if it's the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

> I know it can be done with a DNS server but I don't know how or if it's the easiest way

Node port is not recommended approach to expose; it is hard to manage and it reveals security risks.

So you install [ingress](https://I%20know%20it%20can%20be%20done%20with%20a%20DNS%20server%20but%20I%20don%27t%20know%20how%20or%20if%20it%27s%20the%20easiest%20way.), if you are some cloud provider then its that simple

```
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx
```

and then the ingress for the service which you want to expose, for example `nodejs-app`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
  name: ingress-nodejs
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - demoapp.example.com
      secretName: demoapp.example.com.tls
  rules:
    - host: demoapp.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: nodejs-app
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

Comment: Will that make the app accessible outside the Cluster? One of the reasons I'm using NodePort is because with Ingress I can't access it from another PC even on the same network.

Comment: Where the Kubernetes hosted?

Comment: On minikube inside a VM. It's not really necessary to be accessible from outside the network, only inside.